# What's the plural form of hook and eye?

Tags: plural-forms

What's the plural form of 'hook and eye'? Is it 'hooks and eyes' or 'hook and eyes'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixings used in sewing for joining items, each consisting of a separate hook and eye, are known **individually** as '**a hook and eye**' and **collectively** as '**hooks and eyes**'.

> ***Definition of hook and eye noun from the Oxford Advanced Learner's
> Dictionary***
>
> hook and eye noun
>
> **(*plural hooks and eyes*)**
>
> a device for fastening clothes, consisting of a small thin piece of
> metal curved round, and a hook that fits into it

[Hook and eye (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hook-and-eye)

[image]

Comment: "I need two hook and eyes for my bra"(=I need two fasteners) and "I need two hooks and (two) eyes" (=I need four pieces to make 2 fasteners) - such was my (apparently faulty) reasoning...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - decades ago, an elderly aunt, on first seeing Velcro, said 'Oh my! hundreds of tiny hooks and eyes! How clever!'

Answer (score 1):

If described as a method of closure or a fastener or a piece of garment, "hoot and eye" refers to one thing. Thus, "hoot and eyes" is the plural form.

You could use it adjectively:

> Hook and eye fastenings

Comment: Be careful someone doesn't hoot in your eye, Andrew!